# How to get user input to insert multiple records into database from table created with a for loop?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms

I have created a form that requires the user to input information on all fields and then submit the form. My goal is to get the user input and insert it into new records on the database. My current challenges are that since I used a for loop in PHP to create the table/form:

1. I can not access the input from $_POST
2. Not sure how to go about differentiating all of the rows and their inputs from each other (since I used a loop to create them). I was thinking an array...

[Please see a screenshot of the form I am working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMWwF.png)

Below is what I have for my submit button.

```html
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $date = date('m\/d\/Y');
    $ordnum = $_POST['cpOrderNumber'];
    $ponum = $_POST['cpPoNumber'] . $_POST['cpPoNumberF'];
    $palnum = $_POST['palnum'];
    $casecount = $_POST['casecount'];
    $cpsflot = $_POST['cpsflot'];
    $sscc = $_POST['sscc'];
    if(!empty($_POST['cpOrderNumber']) || !empty($_POST['cpPoNumber'])) {
        require_once('mydatabase.php');
        $query = "INSERT INTO ASN (date, ordnum, ponum, palnum, casecount, cpsflot, sscc ) 
                    VALUES ('$date', '$ordnum', '$ponum', '$palnum', '$casecount', '$cpsflot', '$sscc')";
        $insert = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $query);
        if( $insert === false ) {
            die('Could not connect to database');
        }
    }
    else {
        die('Please enter the appropriate information'); 
    }
  sqlsrv_close($dbc);
}
```

And here is where I am having difficulty. I can get $date, $ordnum, and $ponum to insert into the database however $palnum will not. As you can see from what I've commented out I have tried to use an array.

```html
   

 <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x < 25; $x++) {
         echo
             '<tr id="' .$x. '">
             <td style="font-size: 160%" name="palnum" id="pallet">' .$x. '</td>
             <td id="caseCount"><input type="number" name="casecount" id="inputText_Small" maxlength="2"/></td>
             <td id="hilltopLot"><input type="text" name="cpsflot" id="inputText_Order" value="" maxlength="10"/></td>
             <td id="sscc"><input type="number" name="sscc" id="inputText_Medd"  value="" maxlength="4"/></td>
             </tr>';
    $palnum[$x] = $x;
    //$palnum[$x] = 'palnum'.$x;
    //$palnum = $palnumx.$x;
    //$palnum1 = $palnum[1];
    }
    //echo count($palnumx);
    //echo $palnum[1];
    ?>
```

Comment: well this could be why ... `$palnum = 'palnum';` you need to format that like `$palnum = $_POST['palnum'];`. Additional note to this, your document should have only one of each `id` on the page or your DOM is invalid, look into using `class` to style your elements in your loop.

Comment: As I look at this there are more and more issues ... ugh ... I think you need to find a tutorial on how `forms` work

Comment: Sorry, I originally had it the way you specified but I was experimenting a bit before posting the question. I've edited that part.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for this. not 100% though. Basically, you can name an input wityh brackets to make it behave like an array in the post.

```
<input name="recurringName[]" value="moo" />
<input name="recurringName[]" value="moo2" />
```

if you do that, in the post you can access data this way

```
$_POST['recurringName'][0] == 'moo'
$_POST['recurringName'][1] == 'moo2'
```

i hope this helps! let me know if i did not understand you clearly